# Xcode 6.1, iOS 8.1. SQLite Database No Longer Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have been developing a fairly large application for my college work. I finished the development of this application several weeks ago, and everything was working fine. However I ran the app again yesterday and it no longer connects to the SQL database. I believe this could have been triggered by reseting the simulator and cleaning the app, as no code or the database has been modified.

After a bit of research, other people seem to be have had the same problem. I have tried cleaning the app, reseting the simulator, deleting simulator files etc. However with no luck.

Any suggestions on how to fix this please?
Thank you!

**Edit:  I have been following this tutorial: youtube.com/watch?v=73XRidPrLwY&feature=youtu.be The project worked fine and now is no longer working, nor are any other versions I have saved or the demo from that tutorial (which we all working). Is this an issue with the software?**

Comment: Please add the code, in which you are facing problem

Comment: @MidhunMP The code of the whole project? I have been following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=73XRidPrLwY&feature=youtu.be

The project worked fine and now is no longer working, nor are any other versions I have saved or the demo from that tutorial (which we all working). Is this an issue with the software?

Answer (score 0):

did you check your bundle files and make sure that you have your sqlite file present in the directory, where your trying to open the db and execute the query. i think you failed to create or copy the db in your directory. or your accessing wrong path.

Comment: The database exists as i could previously connect to the database any no code has been edited. Could this be an issue with resetting the simulator? I have various back ups of the app saved, which all worked and none of them are now either.